# Espresso test for Horizontal Scroll View

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have following HorizontalScrollView which I add items to it programmatically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.detail.MovieDetailViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:visibleGone="@{vm.isTrailersVisible}">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/trailers"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/trailer_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:items="@{vm.trailers}" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And here I add items to it :

```
@JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("items")
fun addItems(linearLayout: LinearLayout, trailers: List<Video>) {

    linearLayout.removeAllViews()
    val context = linearLayout.context

    for (trailer in trailers) {
        val thumbContainer = context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.video, linearLayout, false)
        val thumbView = thumbContainer.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.video_thumb)

        thumbView.apply {
            setOnClickListener {
                val playVideoIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Video.getUrl(trailer)))
                context.startActivity(playVideoIntent)
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(thumbContainer)
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a `Espresso` test for it. I want to scroll `HorizontalScrollView` and click on third item. Until now I wrote following test:

```
@Test
    fun shouldBeAbleToDisplayTrailer() {
        onView(withId(R.id.list)).perform(RecyclerViewActions
                .actionOnItemAtPosition<MovieViewHolder>(8, click()))

        onView(withId(R.id.trailer_scroll_view)).perform(nestedScrollTo()).check(matches(isDisplayed()))

        // intended(Matcher<Intent> matcher) asserts the given matcher matches one and only one
        // intent sent by the application.
        //intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)))
    }
```

But I do not know, how to scroll `HorizontalScrollView`. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just two clicks away:

1. Check `scrollTo()` View Action implementation:

   ```
   public static ViewAction scrollTo() {
       return actionWithAssertions(new ScrollToAction());
   }
   ```
2. Check `ScrollToAction()` implementation:

   ```
   /** Enables scrolling to the given view. View must be a descendant of a ScrollView or ListView. */
   ```

   The view should fulfil below constraints to apply `ScrollToAction()` to it. I agree that `ScrollToAction()` description can be improved a bit:

   ```
   withEffectiveVisibility(Visibility.VISIBLE),
   isDescendantOfA(
       anyOf(
           isAssignableFrom(ScrollView.class),
           isAssignableFrom(HorizontalScrollView.class),
           isAssignableFrom(ListView.class))));
   ```

   And the answer is - use `ViewActions.scrollTo()` to scroll `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is how to scroll HorizontalScrollView and `click on third item`.

Comment: First - make sure `HorizontalScrollView` is visible to the user. Then perform `onView(View_matcher_that matches_3rd_trailer).perform(scrollTo())`